# Team Planner app error 'The App is not configured yet'

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-web-apps

I've downloaded the Team Planner app but when I add it to a page I get 'An error occurred. The App is not configured yet' What do I need to do? I'm using SharePoint Online.

Comment: I'm getting in the Technical Details: TECHNICAL DETAILS
ERROR:
You don't have the right permissions to show this plan. Make sure you are a member of the plan's Office 365 group.

CALL STACK:
Error: You don't have the right permissions to show this plan. Make sure you are a member of the plan's Office 365 group.
    at https:/  t/files/sp-client-prod_2019-08-16.010/sp-planner-webpart-bundle_en-gb_e551d967c8ba9d5bac661f3a29e82f8a.js:1:3282482

Answer (score 0):

When logging into O365 do you have planner as a product option? If not your license may not be active.

Option 2: some apps are not currently working if you are using a non-commercial version of O365 (GCC, GCCHigh etc).

Comment: Actually found it. Yes we have Planner

Comment: Could it be that I'm not in the right O365 Group? How could I test?